# Using pandas groupby feature, how to query a subset of data and put it into a list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Using python 3.7 and panadas, What is the proper way to ask for all accounts that belong to 'building x' ?

Excel data

```
Building    Account Sales rep
23          1234567       Bob
24          7654231     Steve
25           12ae23       Bob
23           A11111      Jeff
26           A22222      Jeff
26           A33333       Bob
            A444448      Mike
```

Here is my code that i am trying

```
Import pandas as pd
table_data  = pd.read_excel(‘excel.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', dtype=str)
buildings = table_data[‘Building’].tolist()
accounts = table-data[‘Account’].tolist()

grouped_by_building = table_data.groupby("Building")[["Building", "Account", "Sales rep"]]
for item, group in grouped_by_building:
    print(item, group)
```

Im wanting to query and get results of say, all accounts that belong to building 26.

OUTPUT

```
Building_26_list = [‘A22222’, ‘A33333’]
Building_23_list = [‘1234567’, ‘A11111’]
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to query just the buildings to iterate over.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to access the groups property of the GroupBy object.
Its done as follows:

```
grouped_by_building = table_data.groupby("Building").groups
for item, group in grouped_by_building.items():
    print(item, group)
```

Look that you use the .items() function to get the dictionary {item: [..., ...]} as a list of tuples [(item, [...,...]), ...]